# Application Crash randomly when I invoke an Activity launcher method

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash

When one of the two buttons that invoke the follow listener are pressed

```
OnClickListener mSportiveListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String title = getResources().getString(
                R.string.function_sport_i);
        String category="SPORT";
        startFunctionSelector(title, category);
    }
};

OnClickListener mClassicListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String title = getResources().getString(
                R.string.function_classic_i);
        String category="CLASSIC";
        startFunctionSelector(title, category);
    }
};
```

The often the application crash with any details about the error that happens exactly on the line

```
startActivity(selector);
```

of the method

```
public void startFunctionSelector(String title, String functionCategory) {
    Intent selector = new Intent(Home.this, FunctionSelector.class);
    selector.putExtra("Title", title);
    selector.putExtra("FunctionCategory", functionCategory);
    try {
        startActivity(selector);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The error isn't related with `FunctionSelector.class` since whatever content I put in that the behavior is exactly the same  (I have tried also with an Hello World)

Unfortunately for some strange reason Eclipse doesn't give me any details about the error only a generic SourceNotFound 
with

```
// Compiled from Handler.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class android.os.Handler {

  // Method descriptor #11 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public Handler();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 8]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: android.os.Handler
```

But nothing specific about the issue.

**MORE DETAILS**

The onCreate of FunctionSelector, but as I have said crash also if I leave only an helloWorld in this Activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            setContentView(R.layout.selector_gui);

            selectorTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
            functionCategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("FunctionCategory");

            buttonBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btBack);
            buttonBack.setOnClickListener(mBackListener);

            txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtTitle.setText(selectorTitle);

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaFunzioni);

        }
```

if I try to use the emulator and I go in the AllMessage (unfiltered per App) I can see

```
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b2f46948 that was originally bound here
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b2f46948 that was originally bound here
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550): null
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b2f46948 that was originally bound here
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-11 14:25:51.139: W/ActivityManager(1201): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@b3149200
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b2f7f7c0 that was originally bound here
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b2f7f7c0 that was originally bound here
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/ActivityThread(1550):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550): null
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b2f7f7c0 that was originally bound here
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 14:25:51.139: E/StrictMode(1550):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Try-catch blocks should not be used to mask errors/crashes. Remove the try-catch and run it again. Make it crash and post a stack trace from logcat -- the one you've posted doesn't seem to show anything about the source of the crash.

Comment: Without more details, I'm going to assume you forgot to put the activity definition in the manifest.

Comment: @Karakuri Initially I haven't used any try catch, I have used the try catch hoping that printStackTrace(e) could help to figure more details about the error... but the result is exactly the same

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA no the activity is in the manifest and sometimes works fine, sometimes no... unfortunately the reported info are all the information that Eclipse have gave to me

Comment: Then let's see the FunctionSelector's onCreate. And you can remove the service leaked messages. Those are just telling you that they weren't closed properly (if your application is crashing, of course they weren't closed properly!).

Comment: Maybe you're passing in a null context sometimes when you create the intent with Home.this. I dunno. I guess all you can do besides showing onCreate or onResume is put logcat method calls in some places. After you create the selector Intent, put: String logMessage = (selector == null) ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL"; Log.d("SELECTOR STATUS:", logMessage); <--See how that goes, I guess. That's all I can think of to help you without more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps

1) Try to include the full path of the activity when initialize the Intent for example

```
Intent selector = new Intent(Home.this, com.yourpackagename.YourActivity.class);
```

same thing in the activity declaration in manifest

2) Verify that all resources are correctly linked and there are no errors in the manifest and in the xml files of the gui

3) Assuming that you have declared the Activity in the manifest, and the resources in the on create are correctly initialized. Probably Something goes wrong in the Eclipse caches delete .metadata folder in your workspace and try to re-import the project.